# Task Behaviour in a process

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, task

My code does not have a problem actually but its a case of performance issue which I may run into.

According to what I know about tasks, a task which starts first say TaskA can be running parallel with another task say TaskB but TaskB may finish and exit its thread before TaskA completes its work. So in my code, I'm trying to proceed with an operation but first knwow the task status. Is it true that this task called `TaskResult` in my code will complete before the preceeding lines of codes will run or should I use a `Task.Wait()` on it if that's what I want?

```
 public virtual async Task<OperationResult> DeleteAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression)
        {
            Task TaskResult = await _DbContext.Set<TEntity>().RemoveRange(IEnumerable<TEntity>);
            if (TaskResult.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
            {
                return new OperationResult()
                {
                    Message = "",
                    ReturnObject = null,
                    Status = OperationStatus.Deleted,
                    Succeeded = true
                };
            }
            if (TaskResult.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted)
            {
                return new OperationResult()
                {
                    Message = "",
                    ReturnObject = null,
                    Status = OperationStatus.UnknownError,
                    Succeeded = false
                };
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `await` keyword will stop execution of your method until the `Task` is completed. Once complete, `await` will either return the result of the `Task`, or throw an exception that happened inside the `Task` (if there was one). So there is no point testing to see if a `Task` faulted if you already awaited it, because if it faulted, `await` would have thrown an exception.

Just wrap it in a `try`/`catch` block.

But your code won't even compile because:

1. [`DbSet<T>.RemoveRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.removerange?view=efcore-2.1) doesn't return a `Task` because it doesn't actually talk to the database at all. It just removes the records in memory. You need to call [`DbContext.SaveChangesAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.savechangesasync?view=efcore-2.1) for your changes to be committed.
2. You're not actually passing a list of objects to `RemoveRange`. (Did you change that code for this example?)
3. Once you await a `Task`, the `await` keyword returns the result of that `Task`, not the `Task` itself.

Here's an example of how you could write that:

```cs
public virtual async Task<OperationResult> DeleteAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression) {

    _DbContext.Set<TEntity>().RemoveRange(somethinghere);

    try {
        //commit the changes
        var result = await _DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        //result will be an int (the number of records changed), not a Task

        //if we got this far, we succeeded
        return new OperationResult()
        {
            Message = "",
            ReturnObject = null,
            Status = OperationStatus.Deleted,
            Succeeded = true
        };
    } catch (Exception e) {

        return new OperationResult()
        {
            Message = "", //you can use e.Message here if you want
            ReturnObject = null,
            Status = OperationStatus.UnknownError,
            Succeeded = false
        };
    }
}
```

Note that you could just put:

```
await _DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

If you don't intend on using `result`.

Comment: Thanks alot for the clarification. The passing of objects to `RemoveRange()` was a typographical error.